# AES-256 compatible for both c# and android

Tags: c#, java, android

I am developing an android application in which i need to encrypt files from my c#     application and decrypt it from android application and vice versa through AES-256. any guide or help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295110/aes-encryption-in-java-and-decryption-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could (and probably should) use the AES-256 implementation that is included in the C# and Java standard libraries. For details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295110/aes-encryption-in-java-and-decryption-in-c) as already stated above.

If for any reason you can't or don't want to: I wrote an [AES-256 implementation in Java](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/security/SHA256.java), I guess porting it to C# would be easy.