# Objective-C -- How to call this method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, aes, encryption

I am using the code found at http://pastie.org/966473 to encrypt/decrypt strings using AES in Objective-C (for iPhone).

I placed the two methods in a file called AES.m. The AES.h looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AES : NSObject

@end
```

I am trying to call the encrypt method like this:

```
NSString *strData = txtText.text;
NSMutableData *objNSData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];

 AES *myScript = [[AES alloc] init];

 objNSData = [myScript EncryptAES:txtPassword.text];
 strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",[objNSData description]);
```

But it doesn't work. It says it can't find the method. I did try importing both AES.h and AES.m, but no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AES string encryption in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289870/aes-string-encryption-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `- (NSMutableData*) EncryptAES: (NSString *) key;` to your AES.h file between `@implementation` and `@end`.