# Encryption method for iPhone and Android

Tags: java, android, ios, encryption, aes

I have tried to generate an encrypted text using AES algorithm In both ( Android and IPhone ) platforms but the problem is even we use the same encryption decryption library (AES-128)  and with the same fixed variables  ( Key , IV ,mode) but I get two different result for them.

I appreciate any help . :(

The below code presents the used encryption and decryption methods ,

**Code version for Android:**

- Key = “123456789abcdefg” ;

  - IV   = “1111111111111111” ;
  - Plain text = “HelloThere”;
  - Mode = “AES/CBC/NoPadding” ;

Code :

```
  public class Crypto {
public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
}



public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
}


private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(“CBC”);
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance(“SHA1PRNG”);
        sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, “AES”);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(“AES”);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
}
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, “AES”);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(“AES”);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
}
public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
}
public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
}
public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
                return “”;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
}
private final static String HEX = “0123456789ABCDEF”;
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b»4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

}

**Code version for IPhone:**

```
- (NSData *) transform:(CCOperation) encryptOrDecrypt data:(NSData *) inputData {

NSData* secretKey = [Cipher md5:cipherKey];

CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

status = CCCryptorCreate(encryptOrDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                         [secretKey bytes], kCCKeySizeAES128, iv, &cryptor);

if (status != kCCSuccess) {
    return nil;
}

size_t bufsize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, (size_t)[inputData length], true);

void * buf = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset(buf, 0x0, bufsize);

size_t bufused = 0;
size_t bytesTotal = 0;

status = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor, [inputData bytes], (size_t)[inputData length],
                         buf, bufsize, &bufused);

if (status != kCCSuccess) {
    free(buf);
    CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
    return nil;
}

bytesTotal += bufused;

status = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor, buf + bufused, bufsize - bufused, &bufused);

if (status != kCCSuccess) {
    free(buf);
    CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
    return nil;
}

bytesTotal += bufused;

CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);

return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:bytesTotal];
```

}

```
 + (NSData *) md5:(NSString *) stringToHash {

const char *src = [stringToHash UTF8String];

unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_MD5(src, strlen(src), result);

return [NSData dataWithBytes:result length:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

}

**Some of my references :**

- http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2009/02/12/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/
- http://code.google.com/p/aes-encryption-samples/wiki/HowToEncryptWithJava

Comment: Please keep in mind that getBytes() method of string is not sure to return same String every time

Comment: Have you tried decrypting the output of your Java and Objective-C versions through this? http://www.everpassword.com/aes-encryptor

Comment: have you tried the basic plaintext.equals(decrypt(encrypt(plaintext))) test? do they return true for both methods?

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation,yes i tried everpassword.com/aes-encryptor and plaintext.equals(decrypt(encrypt(plaintext))) but the result is not the same

Comment: I just posted an acceptable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421146/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-ios-objective-c-result-differs-from-android/56178213#56178213.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES string encryption in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289870/aes-string-encryption-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4):

First thing to check is the bytes you are using.  You list your IV, key and plaintext as characters.  Those characters will get converted to bytes using some sort of encoding.  Check what the **bytes** look like, not the characters.  You need to list everything, byte by byte, on both machines and compare.  Alternatively specify exactly what conversion you are going to use on each machine.  The machine defaults could well be different.

Once you know the input bytes are the same, then we can look for other problems.

As a minor point, it is generally better to use padding, such as PKCS#7; that way you don't have to fit your messages to the cypher's block size.

Comment: Thank you, but i tested the bytes(byte by byte)  but the result is not the same.any suggestion?
for the padding,i tried PKCS padding and no padding modes,the idea is  i am limited with no padding mode because the PHP server use No padding.

Answer (score 3):

oh man, you forgot to use .getBytes("UTF-8"); ...

extremely important.

EDIT:

I know I should improve the quality of this answer but what I said here + what rossum said below is the trick to getting this right.

It's just about cryption/decryption compliance - when you're working across platforms you have to have binary compliance as well.

so dump the raw data and inspect them for discrepancies until your eyes bleed out and you spot and successfully patch that little quirk that makes that difference.

for starters, .getBytes("UTF-8") will get you consistent strings across Java/android environments (because getBytes() doesn't work the way you'd expect it to work unless you read the docs)

Comment: Thank you, i already tried getBytes("UTF-8") for both platforms , but i got different results.

Answer (score 0):

The code has various problems, but your the cause of you getting different ciphertext on each encryption on Android is that you are not specifying an IV, and a random one is being generated. Also you say 'no padding', but the iOS code is doing padding, and the Android is most probably also is by default, since you are not specifying it explicitly. Finally, you do *need* padding if you are encrypting anything that is not a multiple of the block size (as your sample plain text is). `getBytes()` default to UTF-8 on Android, so that is the least of your problems, but do make it explicit.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the provided link, but although i tried the same IV (i put it hard coded) and No padding in iOS code i got different results for both platforms .
i used getBytes("UTF-8") also but still have different results.
For padding type am sorry but the PHP server uses No padding mode,so i am strict to this mode.
Appreciate your help

Comment: 'No padding' only means you have to pad it yourself, otherwise you will get an error. Update your code to show how used the IV.