# Decrypt android AES example on iOS

Tags: android, ios, encryption, cryptography, aes

i have an Android example of AES encryption/decription.

https://github.com/itog/CryptoSample/blob/master/src/com/pigmal/android/ex/crypto/Crypto.java#L35

I want to decrypt this on iOS. It looks allmost impossible. I've found this to make it more easy, but failed:

https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC

I even don't get a good response back from the base64 decoding. Here's my code:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData base64DataFromString:encrypted];
// returns null
NSData *decryptedData = [encryptedData decryptedAES128DataUsingKey:[[CRYPT_SEED dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] SHA256Hash] error:&error];
NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: You must use the same encryption mode and padding for both iOS and android in order to work it properly.

Comment: You are going to need to learn a little about encryption, determine the options and inputs used by the Android code and duplicate them in the iOS code. CommonCrypto is your friend, get to know him. Using encryption without understanding it will probably produce an insure result.

Comment: That's true. But the goal is not to completely secure the data, but to delay potential hacker. I just want to have an encrypted feed for a temporary project.

Comment: I just posted an acceptable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421146/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-ios-objective-c-result-differs-from-android/56178213#56178213.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES string encryption in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289870/aes-string-encryption-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all AES is symmetric cipher algorithm which needs to use exactly the same key for message encryption and also for message decryption.

I have examined your example codes and these are the things that really bother me:

- **different keys**: Android example does not provide any getter or setter for AES key that should be used. Without that you are unable to use the same AES key on Android and iOS.
- **different key sizes**: Android example seems to be using AES-128 but iOS example seems to be using AES-256
- **different cipher modes**: iOS example uses [CBC cipher mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) so you will need to exchange also [IV (initialization vector)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) between your devices. However I don't see any interface to provide/acquire IV in Android example.

I believe these are the main reasons why you are unable to get it working. If you want to use AES then you will need to modify your code to **use the same key** on both devices, **use the same [cipher mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)** on both devices and also use **the same [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29)** on both devices.

Answer (score 2):

Tips:

- You could use a third-party library to do this. Depending on the library, it may be cross-platform so same calls on different platforms will return back same results.

Secure Black Box:
https://www.eldos.com/sbb/platforms.php#product

Crypto++
http://www.cryptopp.com

- You could compile the test AES routine to ensure both AES encrypt and decrypt routine on Android and iOS give the same results.
- You could check the Base64 if it is encoding and decoding correctly. Sometimes it could be Unicode (UTF16) iOS and non-Unicode (UTF8) Android problem. That happened to me when I was doing this.

Comment: Please upvote & tick my answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be because the public keys are different.

There are two things those are stored encrypted. First one is, username/password and second one is the message itself. When you enter your password correctly, the message is decrypted using your pasword and the public key.

The reason we call it as **public key** is, for the same crypting methods, the keys are the same.

Therefore, what I think is, maybe you should look for a procedure that sets the public key to a string of your choice.

Or you may use a simpler method, such as fairplay.

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers have noted is true, it could down to different is key size/mode/padding. There can also be issues with the type of BASE64 encoding. On Android there's a couple of different flags that can produce subtly different outputs. I found `Base64.NO_WRAP`to work.

I also had the similar issue with [AESCrypt-ObjC](https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC) by default it uses a blank [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) and on Android/Java it seems if you don't specify one a random one is generated.

Here's how I specified a blank IV so that iOS could decrypt:

```
private static byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

cipherText = cipher.doFinal(stuffIWantSafe.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String encodedCipherText = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not recommending a blank IV from security point of view for better to have a IV that changes with each message*

*Update: Just released [Android version](https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android) of AESCrypt