# Objective - C - Equivalent Cryptography of Java algorithm

Tags: java, objective-c, web-services, encryption

I already read a lot of topics in this forum and many other threads on the web but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer....

Even knowing that I can get a negative point I need to put this question...

I have several webservices written in java. And until now, just Android apps are consuming this services. Most of all the SOAP messages are encrypted, and I use this class below on both sides (Android and Server), to encrypt and decrypt:

```
public class Crypto {

private static final String engine = "AES";
private static final String crypto = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

static String key = "1234567890987654";
static String _iv = "1234567890987654";

public static byte[] cipher(byte[] data, int mode)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
{
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), engine);
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(_iv.getBytes());
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(crypto);
    c.init(mode, sks, iv);
    return c.doFinal(data);
}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    return cipher(data, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) throws InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    return cipher(data, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
}
}
```

And all this works very well. I'm not interested if this is a good approach, but that's enough for me.

The case now, is that I must write some iOS apps that will consume these webservices, and I must to know how to use the same cryptography in Objective-C, or a cryptography that I can apply on Android, iOS and server side.

I thank you so much and appreciate any tip!

Comment: CommonCrypto provides everything you need. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a porting service.

Comment: I just posted an acceptable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381359/how-do-i-do-a-cross-platform-encryption-method-working-in-both-ios-and-android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a cross language encryptor/ decryptor I would suggest looking here: [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

If you are looking at Encryption technologies provided by Apple then this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html) would be a good place to start.

If you are looking for Objective C code to use as a reference point while encrypting. I would suggest looking at this AES 128 Encryption Object C project on [github](https://gist.github.com/matsuda/9204276).

Finally, this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289870/aes-string-encryption-in-objective-c) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Turtle. i'll take a look at these pages and post the results right after...