# How do I do a cross platform encryption method working in both IOS and android (AES encryption only..)?

Tags: java, swift, swift2, aes

I have been recently assigned a task of encrypting my links and parameters i pass in dataTaskWithRequest in swift. The main headache is it should produce the same output as Android platform. The android team has already created a backend using spring for decrypting the data. The java code is like this

> class AESencrp {
>
> ```
> private static final String ALGO = "AES";
>  private static final byte[] keyValue =
>         new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
>                 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
>
> public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
>     Key key = generateKey();
>     Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
>     c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
>     byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
>     String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
>     return encryptedValue;
> }
>
> public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
>     Key key = generateKey();
>     Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
>     c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
>     byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
>     byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
>     String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
>
>     return decryptedValue;
> }
>
> private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
>     Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
>     return key;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>    I cannot change the method used here and use the inbuilt encryption method of swift. Is there a way of doing AES encryption in swift which is efficient and matches the output of java code

I tried
          - POD Cryptoswift

> ```
>    do {
>
>          let encrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB).encrypt(inputBytes)
>          let encrypted2: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB, padding: PKCS5).encrypt(inputBytes)
>
>
>         let encryptedNSData = NSData(bytes: encrypted, length: encrypted.count)
>         encryptedBase64 = encryptedNSData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
>
>         let encryptedNSData2 = NSData(bytes: encrypted2, length: encrypted2.count)
>         encryPadded = encryptedNSData2.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
>
>
>         let decrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB).decrypt(encrypted)
>         let result = String(bytes: decrypted, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
>         print("result\t\(result )")
>
>     } catch {
>         // some error
>     }
> ```

```
JAVA CODE OUTPUT = "eJvkXYGzEjJ6RbYSp4a3OQ=="

SWIFT CODE OUTPUT = "9UiyETvuHTsN7eIo0HfQ+w=="
```

As u can see there is a difference in both outputs. Why is this?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm looking at this exact issue as well. My java code is server side though, but all else is the same.

Comment: Yes I did .. I will post the answer below

Comment: One good cross platform solution that also supports multiple languages is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). You also get authentication and if needed key derivation.

Comment: I just posted an acceptable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421146/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-ios-objective-c-result-differs-from-android/56178213#56178213.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using crypto swift. You can add this pod through CocoaPods. It's been recommended that you find a native way to solve this issue as crypto swift may affect ur app Performance. Anyway, I couldn't figure a way out other than it.

I was using swift 2.3 . So, Please convert the code if you are using the latest versions of swift

Step 1 : pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.5.2' (0.5.2 is for swift 2.3 only.)

Step 2 : create a string extension

//Crypto Swift

```
func AES_EncryptionKey() -> String {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calender.components([.Day,.Month,.Year], fromDate: NSDate())
    let year = components.year
    var day = String(components.day)
    var month = String(components.month)
    if day.characters.count == 1 {
        day = "0\(String(day))"
    }
    if month.characters.count == 1 {
        month = "0\(String(month))"
    }
    //Mark: Please change the key as per your requirment! I am using a dynamic key now  rather the one specified in question . i.e It changes everday
    let secretKey = "\(String(day))20\(month)u\(String(year))e"
    return secretKey

}


func AESencrypt() throws -> String  {

    //Mark: You have to do the same thing in Android too. If u skip this here skip in android too
    let secretKeyTest = AES_EncryptionKey().toBase64()!



    let inputBytes: [UInt8] = Array(self.utf8)
    let key:        [UInt8] = Array(secretKeyTest.utf8) //16
    let iv:         [UInt8] = Array("0000000000000000".utf8)  //16

    var encryptedBase64 = ""
    do
    {
        let encrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB).encrypt(inputBytes)
        let encryptedNSData = NSData(bytes: encrypted, length: encrypted.count)
        encryptedBase64 = encryptedNSData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

        //Mark: You have to do the same thing in Android too. If u skip this here skip in android too
        encryptedBase64=encryptedBase64.toBase64()!

        //Mark: Follow the same blockMode in both platform. ECB Mode is not recommended. I did it in ECB cuz it was already done in other platform
        let decrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB).decrypt(encrypted)
        let result = String(bytes: decrypted, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print("result\t\(result )")
    }
    catch
    {
        print("FAIL ENCRYPT")
    }
    print("encryptedBase64: \(encryptedBase64)")

    return encryptedBase64

}

func AESdecrypt() throws -> String {
    var decryptedString = "NIL"
    let secretKeyTest = AES_EncryptionKey().toBase64()!

    let key:        [UInt8] = Array(secretKeyTest.utf8) //16
    let iv:         [UInt8] = Array("0000000000000000".utf8)  //16

    //Step1
    let encryptedData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    if let base64Decoded_ = NSData(base64EncodedData: encryptedData, options:  NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
    {

        if var stringBase64 = String(data:base64Decoded_, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        {
            //Step2
            let encryptedDataSecond = stringBase64.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let base64DecodedSecond_ = NSData(base64EncodedData: encryptedDataSecond, options:  NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
            //Step3
            let encrypted = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(base64DecodedSecond_!.bytes), count: base64DecodedSecond_!.length))
            do
            {
                let decryptedData = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .ECB).decrypt(encrypted)
                decryptedString = String(bytes: decryptedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                print("decryptedString: \(decryptedString)")
                print("ALL DECRYPTED")

            }
            catch
            {
                print("FAIL DECRYPT")
            }
        }
    }


    return decryptedString


}



func fromBase64() -> String? {
    guard let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
        return nil
    }

    return String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}

func toBase64() -> String? {
    guard let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
        return nil
    }

    return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
}}
```

Step 3 : The most important thing is cross checking the way of all your methods in both platforms. Do follow all the steps done in one platform in the other too..

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.