# Hide API key in source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, token

I'm building an iOS application where the user send requests to a server, with an API key. Altough the problem occurs when I need to have this key as a static string inside the source code:

```
NSSTRING* secretAPIkey = @"12345secretKey";
```

I've read about the reverse engineering where someone can view your source code, basically.

**My solutions:**
1. multiple static strings, and then combine them into one

```
nsstring *1 = @"1";
nsstring *2 = @"2";
nsstring *complete [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@%@",1,2];
and so on..
```

2. Save it in info.plist.
3. Not sure if keychain is global around all applications , since all users need the same API key.

Any other solutions? What's the best approach?

Comment: First define what level of attacker you are defending against. Consider that an iOS app is encrypted by Apple with an Apple key, no one can examine the binary at rest. In order to obtain the access key the iOS device must be jailbroken and have hacking tools installed. With these tools will launch the app and halt it prior to execution and the binary can be examined at that time. Is this the level of attacker you are protecting against?

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs an internet connection to work, then you can choose to fetch the API key from a webserver with https and authentication, and optionally use certificate pinning to prevent MITM attacks.

Comment: I thought so as well. The problem with an authenticated webserver is if I use, lets say .htaccess basic auth, I still need to write the password and suename in the URL withint the app?

URL in xcode: https://admin:admin@domain.com/secret.php

Where the PHP file will return the key from MySQL.

Comment: This in general requires a user account and login.

Comment: Yeah, but to get the actual key from lets say, a PHP file. I need to secure the PHP file with authentication. Which means that I need to hardcode the ULR with password and username into the app, right?

URL: @"user:password@domain.com/getAPI.php"

Then it will return a value into a abstract string, and save the Key into a string, nsuserdefaults for example, so the request for API doesnt need to be fetched all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the key using AES and put an encrypted version in source code, and then decrypt it later. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289870/aes-string-encryption-in-objective-c). This still can be reverse engineered, but makes it much harder.

Comment: Simple question about encryption and keychain. While the Keychain syntax will look something like this:



KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"something" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:@"superSecretAPIKey" forKey:kSecAttrPassword];



The "superSecretAPIKey" is still a static string within the keychain syntax. Wont that be a problem as well?

Comment: @JimmieMagnusson you're right, that's why I suggest encrypting api key outside of your application and use already encrypted key in source code, so it's immediately accessible by hijacker who will search for strings in source code.

Comment: So, how do you mean encrypting the key outside the app? How do I get it into the app then? Cus the user needs the key to perhaps make an account etc.

Also encrypting the key inside the app can be an idea as well

Comment: You can write a simple desktop app to encrypt the key and then paste an encrypted key as a string into your iOS app. Later you can decrypt your key and send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just create an array of bytes and make a different operations with each byte, for example for first byte your make addition, for second - subtraction, third -  multiplication and so on... As a result you need to get your "secret api key" as a string. So initially your have only array of bytes and anybody don't know how to convert it to text.
2. Or use any encryption algorithm.

Note: But, if you don't work through https, anyone can sniff your request. Also if you work with https, there is a way how to sniff you request too... So, Your approach to the problem initially not right.

Comment: 1. Munging the bytes is not really very effective to an attacker that has gotten that far. 3.If an encryption key is used that just moves the problem to securing that key. 3. Yes, HTTPS must be used and with cert pinning.